# Would a web service layer be beneficial?

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm looking to create an ecommerce website, however I have two possible ideas for the structure of the application.

The first idea would utilize MVC 4 and have an EntityFramework layer to communicate to and from the database. This is fairly straight forward but I don't like the idea of having ALL of the processing happening on the front end of the website.

My second idea was to have a web service that sits in between the MVC application and EntityFramework. This would be responsible for most of the website processing, and would expose only necessary information to the front end of the website to minimize the amount of processing on the front end of the website.

Would this be a better solution, or is there another solution which would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a difference between logical and physical layering.

To avoid premature optimization, you can have all the logical layers you want inside the web application itself (the traditional presentation / business / data approach or another pattern, for example onion architecture).

Later, if needed, you can always optimize and move parts into their own physical layer, and in that case you would have a web service or web API in between. But it all depends on your requirements (multiple consumers of the services?) and environment. You could just as easy scale the web site itself, for example.

So in your case, think about what added value this additional abstraction would have, and if it's worth the extra complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Running all traffic an EF access through a web service layer internall has the following benefits:

- It runs up your budget because you do add a lot of slow processing overead (string parsing) into a high throughput low level interface.
- It absolutely makes sure you have a low performance because of the added latency.
- It totally makes sure you spend a lot of more working hours to get a solution because you need to implement and test a web servie for any small database access.

THere is no reason to run anything internally through a web service interface. It is architectural cancer - out of control complexity growth. Web services are a user interface layer and a trust boudary and should be the end of an application. If you make a web commerce website (and most likely that is quite trivial and small compared to something like amazon) there is no need to get involved into elements that make things a lot more compelx without any gain.

Answer (score 0):

DEPENDS!

Building an eCommerce web site from scratch I would use a client mvc web site with a responsive pattern in mind, so it will fit to all devices , and use EF WebApi as the data layer to generate XML/JSON.

Comment: Can you specify the reason why?

Comment: Because he likes the advantages I have laid out in my post. Or does not underrstand the technology, sadly. The EF WebAPI interface is meant as application boudary between a backend server and a front end client (like a WPF application, i.e. a trust boudary) and using it in a singular system is the usual abuse of people not caring about perforamnce. Sadly happens way too often.

Comment: TomTom , I think your the one one who "does not underrstand the technology" because what I have pointed out is the new era today of building new modern web-sites today.
Why I suggested it? I'm not sure , I like to use new things and keep up to date.